# How to get Apache to follow symlink instead of downloading it?

Tags: apache-http-server

I am just using the standard apache config file which mentions that it follows symlinks, but when I hit the url `http://localhost/test` it downloads the symlink file instead of following it.  What config do I need to change to get apache to follow the symlink instead of downloading it?

This is an ls on the directory:

```
$ ls -al
total 10
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM  SYSTEM  0 Oct 20 10:55 .
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM  SYSTEM  0 Aug 26 12:27 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 me None   47 Oct 20 10:14 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx  1 me None   29 Oct 19 17:10 test -> /home/me/projects/test
```

This is in my apache config file:

```
<Directory "D:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Give more info on the system setup. Are you running Cygwin and pointing the symlink in question to an NTFS drive under Windows? What do you mean with "download the symlink" - what contents does the downloaded file contain? Is it a text file?

Comment: I remember Cygwin do store symlinks as plain text files, so they're only treated as symlinks if the binary is compiled with cygwin libraries. Where did you get your Apache?

Answer (score 1):

This could be down to permissions. First you need to figure out what user the apache server is running under. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as). On my server the user is `apache`.

Then run this from within your directory:

```
chgrp apache test/
chmod g+xr test/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no symbolic links in Windows. You may achieve the desired effect using [mod alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).